# FormGroup item input not updating on Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm new to Angular 2. I'm trying to create a simple form using `FormBuilder` & `FormGroup`. But for some reason whatever I'm entering in the username field from view is not updating on my component, can't see new value when I'm clicking submit button. My view and component code is as below, can someone please point me what is the issue.

**login.ts**

```
import { Component} from "@angular/core";
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
selector:"login-page",
templateUrl: "login.html"
})

export class LoginPage {
    loginForm : FormGroup;
    constructor(formBuilder :FormBuilder) {
        this.loginForm = formBuilder.group({
            'username':[
                '',
                Validators.required
            ]
        });
    }

     validate() : boolean {
         if (this.loginForm.valid) {
             return true;
         }
     }
    submit() : void {
        if (!this.validate()) {
            console.info("Invalid input")
        }
        let control = this.loginForm.controls['username'].value;
        console.log(control);
    }
}
```

**login.html**

```
<ion-header style="text-align:center">
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Please login</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

    <h3 style="text-align:center">Welcome to your first Ionic app!</h3>


   <form class ="list" [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
      <ion-item class="loginInput center">
          <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" name='username' ngControl="username" ></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <div class="loginBtn"><button  style="width: 140px" ion-button type="submit">Login</button></div>
   </form>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

`<ion-input type="text" name='username' ngControl="username" ></ion-input>`

to

```
<ion-input type="text" [formControl]="loginForm.controls['username']" ></ion-input>
```

Comment: Thanks @Prerak, its working fine with your suggested change

Answer (score 1):

You need to do below changes.

*.ts*

```
loginForm : FormGroup;

constructor(formBuilder :FormBuilder) {
   this.loginForm = formBuilder.group({
      username:['',Validators.required]
   });
}
```

*.html*

```
 <form class ="list" [formGroup]="loginForm" (submit)="submit(loginForm)">
    <ion-item class="loginInput center">
       <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
       <ion-input type="text" name='username' formControlName="username" ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div class="loginBtn">
       <button style="width: 140px" ion-button type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
 </form>
```